# I lost my data on bcache after setting the mode to writethrough

Tags: mount, bcache

This is my first attempt to ask a question on StackExchange so please expect a not so well organized question.

I had 1 512G SSD and 1 4T HDD set up with bcache on Ubuntu 20.4 to be used for nextcloud data directory storage, I was feeling like the io speed is unreasonably slow since I am using a NVMe SSD but I am only getting around 150MB io speed.

I set the bcache mode as writethrough but it didn't help, so I gave up but later discovered all the original data on the bcache disappeared with only little data left(I can still access the mounted drive, but there is just a tiny bit of data) so I try to remount(umount and mount) the drive but it tells me "mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/bcache0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

I tried to rebuilt the bcache with wipefs and make-bcache again but I still cannot mount the drive(mount /dev/bcache0 /media/), can anyone help with this? I will try to provide as many information as possible.